# Is it plausible that a memory slot in a motherboard could be 'bad'?

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a dual socket ASUS motherboard with dual Intel CPUs installed and 4x 16GB RAM per CPU.

During an initial controlled stress test on the CPU and memory read/write, something failed.

Removing that CPU and moving all memory to CPU 1, the system continued to work, however now a replacement CPU has arrived, the system will not boot if there is memory installed in slot 1 of CPU 2. With memory in slots 3, 5 and 7 the system boots, can find all CPU cores and all memory and will function.

I have tried exchanging memory sticks and the issue does not follow the memory.

What is the interconnect between the CPU and RAM through the motherboard? Has the motherboard failed that one RAM slot? Or has the RAM got a direct link between memory pins and CPU pins, implying the new CPU is faulted on one of its memory channels?

I will rebuild the system moving CPUS between slots and see if the issue moves with the CPU, but would like to get some external opinion that strengthens my understanding first.

So can a motherboard memory controller fail on a single channel? Has it occurred to any users here before?

**Edit:**

Motherboard uses the FLCGA 2011-3 layout CPUs and demands registered RAM as minimum.

Comment: Sockets can fail.  Try contact cleaner.

Comment: The sockets are the weak points, unless there are visible (and severe) scratches on the PCB. Newer CPUs have the memory controller on board (you don't mention what CPU this is), so you could have an issue with either the CPU socket, RAM socket, CPU itself, or potentially on the PCB. Look for debris, bent / missing pins, etc... (and try cleaner as sawdust suggested)

Comment: I once had a motherboard that would burn out any ram stick you put into one slot. Its very plausible.